# Print Linux-friendly pointer address

Tags: c, linux

Sorry if this is a very simple question, but I am new to C and Linux in general.

I am trying to print the address of a pointer using `printf("Address is %p\n", ret);` on a Linux machine. The output is similar to  `0x7fff7c9b979c`. This pointer is intended to point to the location of another instruction within the program, and I'm trying to figure out what instruction that is. However, if I try to disassemble the program using gdb I see instructions with codes like `0x400650`. These two sets of codes don't seem to match up in any way. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: `%p` prints void pointers, which can only portably hold *object* (= data) pointers. There isn't a portable way to obtain instruction addresses. You could perhaps manually print out the constituent bytes of a function pointer, though.

Comment: Also, you should look at `/proc/<pid>/maps` first to see where the executable code is mapped.